# Does anyone know of tools for running a Pocket Empires (traveller) games via e-mail?

Tags: traveller, tool-recommendation

I'm interested in running a game of Pocket Empires (traveller), but the system is fairly complex, and my players are a bit out of their depth here so I'll be receiving their decisions via e-mail and then update each system (all the empire characteristics).
Is there a fairly simple way of running a Pocket Empires this way? Is there out there any kind of software or method to help keep track of all the player's empires (characteristics)?

Answer (score 2):

## Spreadsheets

There have been a few spreadsheets over the years.

- [[ANY] Sector Generator (zip)](http://www.travellerrpg.com/CotI/Discuss/showthread.php?t=13208) - XLS Sector generator using basic generation for CT, MT, TNE, T4, or T20. (MGT has changes in world gen; GT can use the CT method, but doesn't actually include System Gen)

I can't find the T4 PE specific spreadsheets at the moment, but I know 2 or 3 were done in the heyday of T4.

## Errata and FAQ

Jo Grant hosts a site that has the FAQ and Errata: [www.pocketempires.com/pe/oldrules.htm](http://www.pocketempires.com/pe/oldrules.htm)

Jo has also revised and updated the PE rules... (same site).

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat elementary, but I have an old Pocket Empires worksheet here:

http://eaglestone.pocketempires.com/scripts/t4tools/PocketEmpires.html

It does the math for you, for one particular empire.  So you'd have to have one of these up for each player.  And there's no way to persist the data.  I should've put it in a spreadsheet!